# Find the probability density function - problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a random variable $K$, given by p. density function $f(x)$:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{4}(1-x^2), &|x|<1,\\
\\
0, &\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$

I'm trying to calculate the p.density function of a variable $Y=4-K^2$, and at some point I'm stuck: (we know that $-1\leq K\leq 1$):
(for $x\in [3,4]$ )
$$
P(Y\leq x)=P(4-K^2\leq x)=P(\sqrt{4-x}\leq K \leq \infty)=\int_{\sqrt{4-x}}^{\infty} f(t)d t=\int_{\sqrt{4-x}}^{1} f(t)d t
$$

Now I need to get integral $\int_{0}^{x}f(s)ds$, but I have no clue how to change these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, with one caveat. You have to remember the negative side of the square root:
$$
P(4-K^2 \leq x) = P(\sqrt{4-x} \leq K \leq \infty) + P(-\infty \leq K \leq -\sqrt{4-x})
$$
Conveniently, the probability density function of $K$ is symmetric around zero, so we can say:
$$
P(\sqrt{4-x} \leq K \leq \infty) + P(-\infty \leq K \leq -\sqrt{4-x}) = 2P(\sqrt{4-x} \leq K \leq \infty)
$$
From there, you are correct, with the additional factor of two, you just have to carry it through:
$$
2\int^{1}_{\sqrt{4-x}}f(t) dt \\
=\frac{3}{2}\int^{1}_{\sqrt{4-x}}1-t^2 dt \\
=\frac{3}{2}\left.\left(t-\frac{t^3}{3}\right)\right|_{\sqrt{4-x}}^1 \\
=\frac{3}{2}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)-\left(\sqrt{4-x}-\frac{(4-x)^{3/2}}{3}\right)\right) \\
=1-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-1\right)\sqrt{4-x} \\
$$
Note that as a sanity check here, you can plug in $x=3$ and $x=4$ and see that the respective probabilities are $0$ and $1$, as we expect.

Differentiate with respect to $x$ to get the pdf.

$$
\frac{d}{dx}1-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-1\right)\sqrt{4-x} \\
=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{4-x}+\frac{1-x}{2\sqrt{4-x}}\right)
$$

Comment: .... I am a bit speechless, since I concentrated so hard on trying to manually convert these two integrals I forgot I could just integrate it. Thank you, very much.